# How to detect NFC tag removal event?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, nfc, contactless-smartcard

I develop an Android app to read/write on contactless smart cards through NFC. I need to detect when the card is pulled out of range. I tried to use

```
 NFCAdapter.OnTagRemovedListener{
        card_connected2.visibility =  View.VISIBLE
        card_connectedgreen.visibility =  View.GONE
        Toast.makeText(this@InquiryActivity, "card is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

but this seems wrong and does not work. I also read about `NfcAdapter.ignore()`, but I can't find any example about how to use it. How can I get the above callback to work?

Answer (score 4):

The `OnTagRemovedListener` interface is used to specify the callback for the `NfcAdapter.ignore()` method. Consequently, you need to call `ignore()` with the desired callback. E.g., if you want to execute the code above, with a debounce timeout of 1000 ms, you could use something like this:

```
// nfcAdapter: your instance of the NfcAdapter
// tag: the tag handle that you obtained from the NFC intent or the onTagDetected() callback

nfcAdapter.ignore(tag, 1000, NfcAdapter.OnTagRemovedListener {
        card_connected2.visibility =  View.VISIBLE
        card_connectedgreen.visibility =  View.GONE
        Toast.makeText(this@InquiryActivity, "card is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
```

Note that `nfcAdapter` and `tag` need to be defined accordingly. The callback function will be invoked on the main (UI) thread.